# Removing files with/without spaces in filename

Tags: shell, find

Hello stackoverflow community, 
I'm facing a problem with removing files that contain spaces in filename, i have this part of code which is responsible of deleting files that we get from a directory,

```
for f in $(find  $REP  -type f -name "$Filtre" -mtime +${DelAvtPurge})
do
    rm -f $f
```

I know that simple or double quotes are working for deleting files with spaces, it works for me when i try them in a command line, but when i put them in $f in the file it doesn't work at all.
Could anybody help me to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

GNU find has `-delete` for that:

```
find "$REP" -type f -name "$Filtre" -mtime +"$DelAvtPurge" -delete
```

With any other `find` implementation, you can use bulk-exec:

```
find "$REP" -type f -name "$Filtre" -mtime +"$DelAvtPurge" -exec rm -f {} +
```

---

For a dry-run, drop `-delete` from the first and see the list of files to be deleted; for second, insert `echo` before `rm`.

Comment: the problem is not in Find command, the problem is in the line rm -f $f, the rest of the code if this function is like this :

Comment: for f in "$(find  $REP  -type f -name "$Filtre" -mtime +${DelAvtPurge})"
do
    rm -f $f
    if [ $? =  0 ]
 
    then
        FctMsg "${CODE_ERR_OK}" "${FIC_TRC}" "Purge OK pour le fichier ${f}"
    else
        FctMsg "${CODE_ERR_WAR}" "${FIC_TRC}" "Probleme pour purger le fichier ${f}"
    fi
done

Comment: @amy You can do all of that with find as well, I just showed how to delete files with find. Parsing find's output is not a good idea at all btw, it's an anti-pattern best way to put it

Comment: if i add the -delete option, will i have to remove the line of rm and the ' if ... else' lines ?

Comment: Why parsing find's output is not a good idea ? can you give me more explanations if you can please ?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 for that.

Comment: So you want to delete files, and print a message for both success and failure? Your question doesn't represent the actual problem you're having then

Comment: Yes, i want to delete all the files in the directory, whether they contain spaces in their filename or not, and printing a message for both success and failure. The problem is the code that i have deletes only files without spaces, those with spaces are not removed, i tried to put the $f between quotes and it didn't work in this fucntion. I'm looking for a solution to remove all the files without changing the structure of the code.

Comment: *without changing the structure* okay, but the loop just prints messages right? It doesn't alter the current execution environment variables etc.?

Comment: the loop removes files and and print messages of success or failure. i want to replace the line rm -f $f by another cmd which is able to remove all the files, not only those without spaces

Comment: there is no such *cmd* though. the loop reads each space separated token into f; like for a file named `foo bar.txt`, f is first `foo`, then in the next cycle it's `bar.txt`. your script is poorly designed, and there is no easy way to amend it without changing the structure

Answer (score 0):

The other answer has shown how to do this properly. But fundamentally the issue in your command is the lack of quoting, due to the way the shell expands variables:

```
rm -f $f
```

needs to become

```
rm -f "$f"
```

In fact, *always* quoting your variables is safe and generally a good idea.

However, **this will not fix your code**. Now filenames with spaces will work, but filenames with other valid characters (to wit, newlines) won’t. Try it:

```
touch  foo$'\n'bar
for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name foo\*); do echo "rm -f $f"; done
```

Output:

```
rm -f ./foo
rm -f bar
```

Clearly that won’t do. In fact, you *mustn’t* parse the output of `find`, for this reason. The only way of making this safe, apart from the solution via `find -exec` is to use the `-print0` option:

```
find "$REP" -type f -name "$Filtre" -mtime +"$DelAvtPurge" -print0 \
| IFS= while read -r -d '' f; do
    rm -f "$f"
done
```

Using `-print0` instead of (implicit) `-print` causes `find` to delimit hits by the null character instead of newline. Correspondingly, `IFS= read -r -d ''` reads a null-character delimited input string, which we do in a loop using `while` (the `-r` option prevents `read` from interpreting backslashes as escape sequences).

Comment: Thank you @Konrad, would you please tell me what does this option  -print0 | read -r -d '' f   do ?

Comment: @amyhart It delimits the output items of `find` by the zero character instead of by newlines. This is guaranteed to work because zero characters are invalid in file names (whereas newlines are!). Check out the `find` man page, and the [*Bash Pitfalls* page](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for more details.

Comment: i will try this solution and tell you the results, thank u for your answer

Comment: @amyhart Whoops, I just noticed I had missed a word from my code. Fixed now.

Comment: i've tried and it doesn't work too,   i think the problem is right here  IFS= while read -r -d '' f; do ,  this line is not written properly, there's already a for loop before find

Comment: @amyhart No, there should *not* be a `for` loop before find. That’s the point. My code replaces the *whole* of your code, not merely the `find` sub-command.